# Android Splitting String or changing it using matcher

Tags: java, android, regex

I am splitting this string

```
String xml_getMembermob = "Art C. Cauyao<$@PERX@$>501912568<$@ENDPERX@$>Tessa Rose Brainard<$@PERX@$>510831686<$@ENDPERX@$>"
```

I found out that i cannot split this kind of string on a simple matter so Ive created this code

```
String re1=".*?"; 
String re2="(<\\$@ENDPERX@\\$>)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = p.matcher(xml_getMembermob);
if (m.find())
{
   String tag1=m.group(1);
   Log.i("returned string get", ""+tag1); 
   String replacement = "$1 try $2";
   m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
   String asa = sb.toString();
   Log.i("buffered string" + "",asa);
    //m.appendReplacement(myStringBuffer,"wew");
}
```

now before I am getting an error here on this part

```
m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
```

I got log saying that

```
09-10 10:53:44.878: I/returned string get(1198): <$@ENDPERX@$>
```

So I can conclude that the upper codes are working.

Could you help me split this string or change some of its word so that I could split it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a pattern inside a text and replace it, use this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("find and replace me!");
Matcher m = p.matcher("a very long string that contains zero or more find and replace me! pattern inside");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
boolean result = m.find();
while(result) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "I found you!");
    result = m.find();
}
m.appendTail(sb);
String strWithLink = sb.toString();
```

This code will search inside your string and replaces all "find and replace me!" with "I found you!".